# Problemas autenticacion dinamica

Tags: ajax, autenticación

Estoy realizando una web que se conecta a diferentes servidores para pedir datos.
En cada servidor tengo que autenticarme, lo hago de este modo.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    url: "http://servidor_01:8080?id=capota",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('user:pass'));
    },
});
```

El problema que tengo es que no acepta el usuario y la contraseña, me sale la típica ventana de autentificacion.

Comment: Eso suele ocurrir cuando les pasas credenciales incorrectas, en este caso, puede que el usuario o el password que estás pasando no tengan permiso de acceso.

Comment: En este caso no es ese el problema, las credenciales son correctas, pues las introduzco en la ventana de autentificacion y si que las acepta.

Comment: Dado que tu código está escrito así: `xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('user:pass'));` ... ¿Tú tienes entonces un usuario llamado `user` y su password es `pass`?  O esos son datos para no revelar los datos reales y en tu código tienes los correctos?

Comment: efectivamente, son datos ficticios, pero en codigo tengo los correctos.